# How to select a random row among rows in SQL where the attributes are different?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to retrieve a row among many rows in SQL where for example column A does not equal column B.

For instance:

```
Column A --- Column B
 ABC          ABC
 ABC          ACB
 ABB          ABB
```

I want the output:

```
Column A --- Column B
 ABC          ACB
```

So only one row should be there, how can I form the select query for this?

Comment: What do you mean by random row?

Comment: like if I had 1000 rows, and I only want one of them at randomly @rad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select * From tbl
Where ColumnA <> ColumnB
Order By Random() Limit 1
```